# Opening Business Bank Account in Europe

Tags: bank-account, checking-account, europe

I have an online travel agency in USA and I want to open a business account in Europe to reach out to European customers. As an owner, I am not a resident of Europe. I appreciate if someone direct me how to solve such issue.

Comment: How would you imagine a foreigner to open a bank account in your country? It is probably the same everywhere else. You walk into a bank, show your passport, and open an account.

Comment: Pick a bank, then call their customer service (the phone number is usually listed somewhere on the bank's web site). They will be able to either tell you immediately, or transfer you to somehow who can tell you, what you need to do in order to open a business account with them from abroad.

Comment: [This answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/46442/3546) looks relevant as well, even though that question is about individuals, not companies.